# Server not found all browser on ubuntu

Tags: networking, firefox

I am using a Sony vaio with Xubuntu - Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Struggling with an odd problem browsing the internet. I am connected the internet but can't access any website except Gmail and Google search engine or Yahoo, without being able to access any link through the result of my search, I was able to use software center to download chromium since I thought Firefox my default browser had an issue but I got the same behaviour  from Chromium.

Using terminal I got these info:

```
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ ipconfig
No command 'ipconfig' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ifconfig' from package 'net-tools' (main)
 Command 'iconfig' from package 'ipmiutil' (universe)
 Command 'iwconfig' from package 'wireless-tools' (main)
ipconfig: command not found
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:be:02:ee:c8  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:172993 (172.9 KB)  TX bytes:172993 (172.9 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:3a:fa:28:44  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d441:1543:60ed:70a2/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a02:1205:504e:f700:8c07:b952:591d:f8c0/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:1205:504e:f700:406:ff40:6767:4e81/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:130950 errors:0 dropped:137 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64181 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:153436646 (153.4 MB)  TX bytes:7818221 (7.8 MB)

sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ sudo service network-manager restart
[sudo] password for sa: 
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ ping wwww.ba.com
ping: unknown host wwww.ba.com
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ ping www.google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$
```

I appreciate the comments and tips, after trying several times I was able to set up a static ipv4 addresse and it work , can't recall how I did it since I was following a toturial, but the next day I got back to the same problem and my current configuration as this;

```
ifconfig;

sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:be:02:ee:c8  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:823872 (823.8 KB)  TX bytes:823872 (823.8 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:3a:fa:28:44  
          inet addr:192.168.1.8  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d441:1543:60ed:70a2/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a02:1205:504e:f700:8c07:b952:591d:f8c0/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:98000 errors:0 dropped:411 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:43087964 (43.0 MB)  TX bytes:2701583 (2.7 MB)

route -n;

sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 lo
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ 

traceroute www.google.com;

sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ traceroute www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (172.217.19.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$
```

Could somebody please explain to me the conflict here or the problem, kind of lost here

All right as requested the output of telnet n.a..com 80

sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ telnet www.ba.com 80
Trying 104.66.171.91...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$

****Current configurations *****
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:be:02:ee:c8
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:17370 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17370 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1418792 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:1418792 (1.4 MB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:3a:fa:28:44
          inet addr:192.168.1.8  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d441:1543:60ed:70a2/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a02:1205:504e:f700:8c07:b952:591d:f8c0/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1672187 errors:0 dropped:819 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1057202 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2009166409 (2.0 GB)  TX bytes:212308493 (212.3 MB)

sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$

and the file  /etc/network/interfaces

## interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo
iface lo inet static
address 192.168.1.1
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
dns-search example.com
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 192.168.8.10

also resolv.conf;

## Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)

## DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 192.168.3.45
nameserver 192.168.8.10
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search example.com 8.8.4.4 home

last is interfaces-order;

## interface-order(5)

lo.inet
lo.inet6
lo.@(dnsmasq|pdnsd)
lo.!(pdns|pdns-recursor)
lo
tun*
tap*
hso*
em+([0-9])?(*+([0-9]))*
p+([0-9])p+([0-9])?(*+([0-9]))*
@(br|eth)*([^.]).inet6
@(br|eth)*([^.]).ip6.@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(br|eth)*([^.]).inet
@(br|eth)*([^.]).@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(br|eth)*
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).inet6
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).ip6.@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).inet

This is the latest config to shorten the "chat" the the comment section

sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for sa: 
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:be:02:ee:c8
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:17585 (17.5 KB)  TX bytes:17585 (17.5 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:3a:fa:28:44
          inet addr:192.168.1.115  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d441:1543:60ed:70a2/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a02:1205:504e:f700:8c07:b952:591d:f8c0/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:52244 (52.2 KB)  TX bytes:15243 (15.2 KB)

sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ routen'n

> ^C
>   sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ route -n
>   Kernel IP routing table
>   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>   0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
>   169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
>   192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
>   sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$

Comment: dude you don't even have IPv4 address ...... so your only following ipv6 it's magic that you can even reach google :D but that's the thing make sure that you have ipv4 set up correctly then try to reach outside world..... i know that ipv6 is already on world but not as we can see on this example tools are already prepared to be using solely 6

Comment: Oh well since you realized from my post that my knowledge in this matter is minimal to even notice that I dont have an ipv4 address I think it would been wiser to instruct me on how to do so. Well I did dfolliw your note and tried to apply the instructions in ythe folliwing link but still no change other than the ip address i assignd appread when i ifconfig   (inet addr 192.168.0.100) just like thr link, since i wasnt sIure how to choose one . http://www.tecmint.com/set-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-15-10-server/

Comment: Make sure you have a gateway configured as well, and you are able to ping that gateway. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Ainrudh_Malhotra could you please check my update on the main post as the problem still exist and I think I don't have the gateway set up properly

Answer (score 3):

I see you have IPv6 addresses **only** configured on **wlp3s0** interface

> inet6 addr: 2a02:1205:504e:f700:8c07:b952:591d:f8c0/64 Scope:Global
>
> inet6 addr: 2a02:1205:504e:f700:406:ff40:6767:4e81/64 Scope:Global

So all those websites which are accessible or hosted on IPv6 address will be accessible like www.google.com

```
dig www.google.com AAAA

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> www.google.com AAAA
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33677
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     300 IN  AAAA    2404:6800:4002:804::2004

;; Query time: 151 msec
```

And all those which are not hosted over IPv6 won't work, like www.ba.com

```
dig www.ba.com AAAA

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> www.ba.com AAAA
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30440
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.ba.com.            IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ba.com.     60  IN  CNAME   www.ba.com.edgekey.net.
www.ba.com.edgekey.net. 21600   IN  CNAME   e8308.b.akamaiedge.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
b.akamaiedge.net.   1000    IN  SOA n0b.akamaiedge.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1476968242 1000 1000 1000 1800

;; Query time: 354 msec
```

As of why ping and route commands are not working

> sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ route
>
> Kernel IP routing table Destination
>   Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>
> sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ ping wwww.ba.com
>
> ping: unknown host wwww.ba.com
>
> sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ ping www.google.com
>
> connect: Network is unreachable

IPv6 commands for these two utilities are a bit different, Use :

```
route -6
ping6 www.google.com
```

It is showing **unknown host** for **www.ba.com**, Since it was not able to resolve its AAAA(or IPv6) record. Also it is showing **Network is unreachable** for **www.google.com** is because you have not used **ping6** utility so it tries to reach IPv4 address of www.google.com which in this case is impossible as there is no IPv4 address on the interface.

Comment: Great explanation helped understand the problem, and i was able for a day establish ipv4 to reach other website, but currently the problem came up again , the current config is in the main post as I updated it

Comment: I see you have an IPv4 address now. But still the default route is not towards wlp3s0, You are still getting the default route **0.0.0.0         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 lo** . So check for following things **1.)** Are you able to ping 192.168.1.1, if you are just delete the route with metric 0 **2.)** route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.3.1 dev lo. Hope this helps if it did, Please mark this answer as answered or helped.

Comment: Well I see now and i understand the output of route -n command also the command to delete gw 192.168.3.1 which I did and confined by route -n which did not show lo anymore on the list although the problem persisted unfortunately , with no response when trying to ping www.Google

Comment: I could still ping 192.168.1.1 but can't reach other websites on broswer other than Gmail, Google search engin and Yahoo.

Comment: Can you show output of **telnet google.com 80** and **telnet ba.com 80**

Comment: Could you check the main thread please too long for a comment. Thank you .

Comment: And telnet google.com also

Comment: Got connected, throughout ipv6 I guess from the address it showed

Comment: Thats what I thought, Your IPv6 is working but IPv4 is not able to reach internet. So when running in dual stack mode(both IPv4 and IPv6) and dns replies an ipv6 address. The connection to the website will be made from IPv6 address. So IPv4 though able to reach gateway and dns its not able to reach to the internet(maybe nat not working). Solve that problem will be solved surely.

Comment: I appreciate your guidance so far and detailed explanation , and I was wondering if you could instruct me how to fix this problem and what is causing it from my configurations ?#

Comment: Its not up to you. Ask the network administrator to NAT your IP so that you can go to the internet, Since you have a private IP on your machine and it is not routable over the internet.

Comment: Well is there a way where I could achieve this with auto generated ipv4 ? I don't have this issue with my phone, yes I am connected to a dorm wireless network, thus I don't have any admin priv.

Comment: Well if its a wireless network you don't need static IPs just select DHCP from network manager IPv4 settings. You will get an ipv4 address.

Comment: Well, I did that from network connections ipv4 setting choose Automatic dhcp, a new up got created 192.168.1.115 but had 192.168.1.1 as default when requesting route -r so deleted that as default and added the new created ip confirmed by requesting route -r but when checking netstat -r the up address is not showing up and I can't connect to website such as ubuntu.com still could connect with telnet Google.com 80

Comment: What route did you delete ? Did you select wlp3s0 for automatic dhcp? The new IP is on wlp3s0?

Comment: Yes all wlp3s0 current conf; sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ route -n
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.115   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
sa@sa-VPCW11S1E:~$ netstat -r irtt Iface
default         android-48a2a3c 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp3s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp3s0

Comment: Start a chat, you dont need netstat its useless right now. Just get the address again, do not delete any route. And update the question with **route -n** please

Comment: Route -n updated in main thread. Still can't start a chat

Comment: Well its getting really confusing now, If its working on other machines and not on this. I don't see the reason why. You can do **/etc/init.d/ufw stop** and check after that! .else a remote session might be in order. I cannot help you via comments any further than this and that too remotely without the access of machine.